# Recover from errant update-index on bare git repo

Tags: git

I am working with a "bare" git repository where the `--work-tree` was initialized as `$HOME` (following https://github.com/randy3k/dotfiles#dotfiles).

I wanted to ignore a certain deleted folder from appearing in the `git status` listing so I did the following:

```bash
 git update-index --assume-unchanged <folder_to_ignore>
```

I think what I should have done was use the `--skip-worktree` flag because now every attempted interaction with the repo gives me a message:

> "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree"

The existing "solutions" I see related to this error say to 1) re-clone to a temporary location and move the `.git` folder to the repo base folder (which didn't work for me) or 2) change your working directory to somewhere outside the repo (I don't think this applies to a work tree set as `$HOME`).

I am looking to "start over", delete all the files in the bare repo, reset/delete all worktrees, delete all `.git` folders, and start fresh avoiding future work tree errors. How can I do this? Keeping in mind Option 1 (above) did not work for me.

Comment: have you tried renaming the directories to a standard git setup ? e.g: `mkdir tmp_fixup/; mv $HOME/.dotfiles tmp_fixup/.git; cd tmp_fixup`, git inspect and fix whatever (with the regular `git` command), then move back that `.git/` directory as `$HOME/.dotfiles/` ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, I still get the `This operation must be run in a work tree` error

Comment: do you have any `GIT_*` variables in your environment ?

Comment: `printenv | grep GIT` yields nothing

Comment: I tried again and everything mysteriously works. Perhaps the work tree is cached or something and the cache expired...